# Can I copy a function with its *current* state?

Tags: state, metaprogramming, raku, continuations, rakudo

Raku's [state declarator](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/state) can be used to give a subroutine or other block its own local state that persists across multiple invocations of the function:

```raku
sub f { state $n++ }
say f; # OUTPUT: «0»
say f; # OUTPUT: «1»
say f; # OUTPUT: «2»
```

I'm aware of two ways to "copy" a function that has internal state: First, I can assign it to a new `&`-sigiled variable with code like `my &f1 = &f`.  This results in `&f1` effectively being an alias to `&f` and means that they share state – anything that alters the state of `&f` or `&f1` will also change the other function's state.

Second, I can make a [clone](https://docs.raku.org/type/Mu#method_clone) of `&f` with code like `my &f2 = &f.clone`.  This will create an independent function with state that is initialized to any default values in `&f` (that is, with `$n` being `Any` for the code above).

However, I'm hopping for a third way to copy `&f` that (like option 1) would preserve the current value of `&f`'s state but that (like option 2) would make that state independent from `&f`'s.  In other words, I'd like to be able to use the commented-out lines below:

```raku
sub f { state $n++ }
say f; # OUTPUT: «0»
say f; # OUTPUT: «1»
say f; # OUTPUT: «2»
my &f1 = &f;
my &f2 = &f.clone;
# my &f3 = ???;
say f; # OUTPUT: «3»
say f; # OUTPUT: «4»
say f1; # OUTPUT: «5»
say f2; # OUTPUT: «0»
# say f3; # (desired) OUTPUT: «3»
```

Is there any way to save `&f`'s state like that (maybe with something fancy with [wrap](https://docs.raku.org/routine/wrap) or similar that I can't think of)?  Or am I just asking to do something that isn't currently possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's not a way - not even if one were willing to write a module that depends on unsupported Rakudo internals.

State variables are currently handled all the way down in the runtime (typically, MoarVM), where they are attached to a bytecode handle. Cloning a `Block` in turn clones the underlying bytecode handle, which [explicitly does not clone the state variables](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/e28e06ded2fb75a206fb4f36dcf0c5dc3ccef8fa/src/6model/reprs/MVMCode.c#L29).